# Python-Rotating Rubik's Cube Face

Tags: python

I am implementing a Rubik's cube solver in Python. The datastructure that I am using is a fourdimensional list of nested lists, which represents the flattened cube as it was to be unfolded.
I am trying to implement a function, to do the rotation of a side of the cube, for example to rotate the uppermost layer, and the output value, should be how the cube will be, like if one had rotated it in real life.

This is how the data structure looks like:

```
cube = 
[[[], [['white', 'red', 'white'], ['green', 'orange', 'yellow'], ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow']], [], []], 

[[['green', 'white', 'blue'], ['orange', 'green', 'yellow'], ['blue', 'orange', 'yellow']],
[['white', 'green', 'blue'], ['red', 'white', 'blue'], ['orange', 'red', 'orange']], 
[['red', 'orange', 'green'], ['white', 'blue', 'green'], ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']],
[['red', 'green', 'orange'], ['orange', 'yellow', 'blue'], ['red', 'red', 'yellow']]], 

[[], [['green', 'blue', 'white'], ['white', 'red', 'blue'], ['orange', 'white', 'yellow']], [], []]]
```

This means that the indexes of the faces are:

```
orangeface = cube[0][1]
greenface = cube[1][0]
Whiteface = cube[1][1]
blueface = cube[1][2]
yellowface = cube[1][3]
redface = cube[2][1]
```

If I wanted to for example, index the middle piece in the white face, it would be `cube[1][1][1][1]`

The function takes as parameter a side of the cube, for example a tuple containing it.
The corresponding data structure of this Rubik's Cube is a list of list of the above mentioned type:
The function which I am currently using to do this is the following:

```
def Clockturn(cube:list, Turning_face:tuple) -> cube: 
    # these 6 conditional statments, tests which of the faces is getting rotated. 
    if Turning_face == whiteface:
        print("Upface")
        # north, change the downermost layer
        cube[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][0][0] = cubecopy[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][0]
        cube[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][1][0] = cubecopy[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][1]
        cube[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][2][0] = cubecopy[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][2]

        # east, change the leftermost layer
        cube[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][2] = cubecopy[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][0][0]
        cube[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][1] = cubecopy[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][1][0]
        cube[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][0] = cubecopy[eastneighbor[0]][eastneighbor[1]][2][0]

        # south, change the uppermost layer
        cube[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][0][2] = cubecopy[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][0]
        cube[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][1][2] = cubecopy[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][1]
        cube[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][2][2] = cubecopy[southneighbor[0]][southneighbor[1]][0][2]

        # west, change the rightermost layer
        cube[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][2] = cubecopy[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][0][2]
        cube[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][1] = cubecopy[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][1][2]
        cube[northneighbor[0]][northneighbor[1]][2][0] = cubecopy[westneighbor[0]][westneighbor[1]][2][2]
    elif Turning_face == greenface:
        pass # not included for code length
    elif Turning_face == blueface:
        pass # not included for code length
    elif Turning_face == yellowface:
        pass # not included for code length
    elif Turning_face == orange:
        pass # not included for code length
    elif Turning_face == red:
        pass # not included for code length
    
    # In this part i rotate the face of the cube, not just the sides of it by doing a rotation of a 2D array transposing the matrix 
    switch_columns(Turning_face)
    transpose_matrix(Turning_face)
```

I want to get a cleaner alternative than my code as to not need to specify the index of each specific case.
Again, I already implemented the function, but I want a Pythonic way to do it, or maybe I should structure my Datastructure differently. If you would do it otherwise, tell me, I am not sure if this is the optimal way.

[image: Picture of rubik's cube flattened]

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/rubik-cube/ (  https://github.com/pglass/cube ) for hints toward more Pythonic data structure representing the cube.

Comment: Do you all think that I should use a Numpy.array for this datastructure?
Will it bring speed advantages?

Comment: My suggestion was to use a totally different approach for a data structure describing the state of the cube: Python class for the entire cube with 26 elements and a Python class for the cube element with -1, 0, 1 as x,y,z coordinate values for current element position in 3D as a tuple (x-,y-,z-coordinate); side color of a cube element in x,y,z direction with None as a color value in the tuple (color-in-X, in-Y, in-Z-direction) for edge elements having only two faces. Using class methods and matrix multiplication for manipulation and visualization of the cube.

Comment: Have you checked out how it is done here:  https://github.com/pglass/cube ? I think speed is not an issue ...